# sum of prime numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I have an exercise:

> Write a program that takes the number n from the input and prints all cases of prime numbers whose sum is equal to n.

For example: input is n = 13 and output is:

```
2 2 2 2 2 3
2 2 2 2 5
2 2 2 7
2 2 3 3 3
2 3 3 5
2 11
3 3 7
3 5 5
13
```

The output is sorted by lexicographic method.

I just could code for finding the prime numbers between 1-n:

```
n = int(input())
lst = []
for i in range(2, n + 1):
    isPrime = True
    for j in range(2, i - 1):
        if i % j == 0:
            isPrime = False
    if isPrime:
        lst.append(i)

print(lst)
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It is unclear what your question is, can you please edit the question and state what it is that you need help with?

Comment: actually there is(line 5) but the output is sorted by lexicographic method

Comment: You have all the numbers so you just need to find out how to sum a list? or just how to add up numbers inside of a loop?

Comment: no I need to find all cases of the prime numbers whose sum is equal to n

Comment: It's still not clear what your question is. Do you want someone to do your homework for you, i.e. design an algorithm for that? What approaches do you know, which ones have you discarded already?

Comment: Your question is still confusing and reads as though you want someone to write the entire program for you (doing the homework for you?), if this is not the case, please edit the post to be more specific in your question. Include any errors you have encountered.

Comment: sadly i don't know any specific algorithm to solve this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822). We require questions to be *specific* and *focused*. It should be pretty clear that "figure out every possible grouping of prime numbers that sums to N, and display them" is a multi-step process. It is your responsibility to try to identify the steps and figure out where you are getting stuck.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Here is my take at the problem.

```
solution = []
primes_up_to_n = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13]

def get_sums(primes, n, path):
    global solution # keep track of solutions found so far.
    if n < min(primes):
        return # no more solutions are possible at this point
    for prime in primes:
        if n == prime:
            solution.append(path+[prime])
        get_sums(primes, n-prime, path+[prime])

get_sums(primes_up_to_n , 13, [])

k = [sorted(x) for x in solution] # order the solutions
print([*map(list, {*map(tuple, k)})]) # remove the duplicates
```

Explanation:

1. we check if the current n is in the prime list. If it is, it means that `path + [n]` is a solution, so we append it.
2. we reccursively call `get_sums` to find further solutions.
   The problem with this approach is that the algorithm doesn't differentiate between `[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]` and `[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2]` for instance. So we get rid of such duplicates in the last two lines.

The code outputs:

```
[[2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3],
[2, 2, 2, 7],
[2, 3, 3, 5],
[13],
[3, 3, 7],
[2, 2, 3, 3, 3],
[3, 5, 5],
[2, 2, 2, 2, 5],
[2, 11]]
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and do not simply write code to specification. Questions like this one are not suitable for Stack Overflow, and code in answers needs to be explained.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel Well sorry about that. I thought that the person had gave it a try, but i will be more careful in the future. For the explanations, i edited my post and i hope it is clearer now.